# Changing Location Settings

Tags: java, android

I am working on an application that needs user's location. I cannot get the location if the user turn the location setting off. Therefore, I follow the android training to prompt the location setting dialog to let the user turn the location setting on: 
https://developer.android.com/training/location/change-location-settings.html

```
public static void settingsRequest(final Activity activity) {
        LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                .addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
        builder.setAlwaysShow(true);

        SettingsClient client = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(activity);
        Task<LocationSettingsResponse> task = client.checkLocationSettings(builder.build());

        task.addOnSuccessListener(activity, new OnSuccessListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LocationSettingsResponse locationSettingsResponse) {
                // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize
                // location requests here.
                // ...
            }
        });

        task.addOnFailureListener(activity, new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                int statusCode = ((ApiException) e).getStatusCode();
                switch (statusCode) {
                    case CommonStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied, but this can be fixed
                        // by showing the user a dialog.
                        try {
                            // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                            // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                            ResolvableApiException resolvable = (ResolvableApiException) e;
                            resolvable.startResolutionForResult(activity,
                                    REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException sendEx) {
                            // Ignore the error.
                        }
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way
                        // to fix the settings so we won't show the dialog.
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

If the location setting is off, the dialog is shown but the problem is that when user touches outside the dialog, the dialog disappears. How can I prevent that? (sth like setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false) )?

note that location setting dialog is not my custom dialog. So I cannot set setCancelable(false)
The dialog shows when these code is exccuted

```
// Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                            // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                            ResolvableApiException resolvable = (ResolvableApiException) e;
                            resolvable.startResolutionForResult(activity,
                                    REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple add this line in your `AlertDialogue()`;

```
 .setCancelable(false)
```

For example;

```
   AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

    alertDialog.setCancelable(false);

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

    // On pressing Settings button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    // on pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: note that location setting dialog is not my custom dialog. Show I cannot set setCancelable(false)

Answer (score 0):

use network provider location instead

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.view.ContextThemeWrapper;
import android.util.Log;




public class MyLocation extends Service implements LocationListener {
    // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 150; // 10 meters
    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 10; // 1 minute
    private final Context mContext;
    // Declaring a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;
    // flag for GPS status
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
    // flag for network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
    // flag for Passive status
    boolean isPassiveEnabled = false;
    Location location; // location

    double latitude; // latitude
    double longitude; // longitude

    public MyLocation(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        getLocation();
    }


    public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
            // getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            // getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            // getting network status
       //     isPassiveEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER);

            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS", "GPS");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }

            }
//            if (isPassiveEnabled) {
//                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
//                Log.d("Passive Provider", "Passive");
//                if (locationManager != null) {
//                    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER);
//                    if (location != null) {
//                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
//                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
//                    }
//                }
//            }
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }

    public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public double getLatitude() {
        if (location != null) {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        if (location != null) {
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }
        return longitude;
    }
    public void showSettingsAlert() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(mContext, R.style.myDialog));
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS Settings");
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        alertDialog.show();
    }

    public void showtimeSettingsAlert() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(mContext, R.style.myDialog));
        alertDialog.setTitle("Date/Time Settings");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Automatic Date & time, Automatic time zone is not Enabled. You have to enable these settings");
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_DATE_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        alertDialog.show();
    }
    public void showHighAccuracySettingsAlert() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(mContext, R.style.myDialog));
        alertDialog.setTitle("High Accuracy Settings");
        alertDialog.setMessage("To get proper address, You have to enable High Accuracy settings");
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
            }
        });
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        alertDialog.show();
    }

    public boolean checkGpsEnable() {

        isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        return isGPSEnabled;

    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        double lat = location.getLatitude();
        double lng = location.getLongitude();
        if (lat != 0.0 && lng != 0.0) {
            setLatitude(location.getLatitude());
            setLongitude(location.getLongitude());
        } else {
            getLocation();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: you can check gps is enabled or not from this class "checkGpsEnable()"